# Moderator Position Open - Nominations Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

We are looking to fill **one** available moderator position here on Russian SE and are looking for interested users.

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing an extra provisional Moderator to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active on the site
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Nikolay has time and again proven himself an outstanding member of this community who can set a good example in both sharing knowledge of Russian and its usage and interacting with the other members of the community in a friendly and professional way.

My opinion is that Nikolay will make a great moderator of this community.

---

Nikolay here. I'd like to abstain from either accepting or declining, pending more input on what the community feels is the kind of moderator Russian SE needs.

Here's what you need to know about me to make an informed yes or no vote. I feel that, given our small userbase, Russian SE is overmoderated as it is. I don't believe we're in any danger whatsoever of being swamped with low-quality posts; in fact, the greater danger is creating a pedantic and unfriendly environment. There is an active moderator who feels more or less exactly the opposite way, and I'd rather avoid a tug-of-war situation. As I said, I'd like to know where the community stands on how high or low we should set the bar for what we consider quality questions.

To put it simpler: I could *represent* a more liberal/laissez-faire approach to moderation, but I don't want to become someone who merely smuggles this approach in, if people are generally fine with the way this site is run now.

Comment: I honestly and openly disagree - I've encountered some very aggressive and nervous behavior on Nikolay's side. Nikolay is a great user and I'd be very not having him in our community. But moderator should be calm.

Comment: @shabunc Fair point. Another fair point, though, is that nearly all of the times I've arguably overreacted have had to do with your decisions as a moderator. I'm a believer in "people before rules", which is why I appreciate the nomination but am somewhat on the fence as to whether I'd be a good fit.

Comment: @NikolayErshov still a very bad sign - irregardless of person, moderator should be calm.

Comment: @shabunc I don't think you're necessarily an impartial judge of how opposite-of-calm I was in my dealings with you; on top of that, I wasn't (and am not now) speaking from a position of authority. "Very aggressive" is not how I'd describe my vehement but thoroughly reasoned opposition to what I perceived as your pattern of moderatorial overreach. You may remember that I ended up seeing your side of things somewhat; still, if you ask me, casually disparaging a useful and purpose-adequate site like otvet.mail.ru on some vague grounds of style or class is what I'd call a "bad sign".

Comment: I believe that moderators should co-exist in a peaceful fashion and see no willingness on your side to do that, honestly.

Answer (score 3):

**russian.stackexchange.com**

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I'm almost always online on this site. Being a member of this community for 3 years, 9 months, I visited it 982 days (~70%).
I want to spend my time and energy on the further development of this community, as well as just to help those who wish to learn Russian. My English is not perfect, so I'm learning English by sharing knowledge of Russian - this is a mutual benefit. And also, to be honest, it is very interesting to try myself as a moderator.

---

#### Participation in other sites:

**stackoverflow.com**

[image]

**stackexchange.com total**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because he seems to be the most active member on this community recently, always providing fast and concise answers.